# How to update Job Title property in User Profile Synchronization?

Tags: user-profile-service

I am using SharePoint 2016. I ran user profile full synchronization, but Job Title and Organization chart(Manager name) are NOT getting "updated" from Active Directory to SharePoint. For example, the new employee information is being added correctly, but existing employees Job Title, manager, etc are not updating. Also, employees deleted in AD are also not being updated in SharePoint. Can someone give me an explanation for this? 
Thank you 
Kalai

Answer (score 0):

For Users deleted in AD should not get synced in SharePoint:-

Make sure that "My Site cleanup timer job" has run successfully in Centration Administration.

When the My Site cleanup job runs, it looks for all users marked for deletion and deletes their profiles.

For Job title and manager not getting values upon sync completion :-

Can you please share screenshot of these user profile properties. Just need to make sure the settings are okay .

Comment: Thank you for your response. "My Site Cleanup Job" is running successfully. Sorry I don't know how to attach a file so I am typing properties mapping. Name: SPS-JobTitle Display Name: Job Title. And for manager Title: Manager Display Name: Manager.

Comment: @yash.kamadar can you help me with my question? Thank you